# How to remove eventlistener

Tags: typescript, events, ionic-framework, server-sent-events

Im building an app with Ionic and I'm using EventSources like this:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
        .then((uuid: any) => {
            this.eventListener = this.events(uuid).addEventListener("message", function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }, false);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
        });
}

events(uuid: any) {
    return new EventSource("http://url.com");
}
```

Its working fine but I want to stop the listener when leaving the view again - something like this:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.eventListener.removeEventListener("message", function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }, false);
}
```

But it doesnt work. How do I remove the listener again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store EventSource you create and callbacks in variables. Only in this case you would be able to reference them, which is required for deletion listeners, 
e.g:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
        .then((uuid: any) => {
            var eventListener = function (e) { console.log(e) };
            var eventSource = this.events(uuid)
            eventSource.addEventListener("message", eventListener, false);
            // then you can
           eventSource.removeEventListener("message", eventListener, false);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```